# OnSwipe method not working in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm working on an app for playing audio files. Created a tab layout with 2 tabs. Used fragment in both of them with `RecyclerView` being used in both of them. The fragment named `LibraryFragment` has this `RecycleView` whose items when Swipped must pass on to the `HomeFragment`, that's what I wanna do. **But even though swiping animation is happening, `OnSwipe` method doesn't works at all.**

This is the method I've used to provide the swiping function to my recyclerview's items under the `LibraryFragment`. Under `OnCreateView` method I call this `initSwipe()` method.

```
 private void initSwipe(){
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT ) {


        private boolean swipeBack = false;
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

          if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
                HomeFragment.audioList.clear();
                HomeFragment.audioList.add(audioList.get(position));
                HomeFragment.libraryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.e(TAG, "onSwiped: " );
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                                int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
            recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                    {
                        swipeBack = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        swipeBack = false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }

        @Override
        public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
            int value = swipeBack ? 0 : super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
            swipeBack = false;
            return value;
        }


    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(libraryRecyclerView);
}
```

please help out.

Comment: did u get any solution??

Comment: Nothing, I removed `swipeBack = false;` statement under `convertToAbsoluteDirection()` function and it was working just for one time. So I changed my layout completely and added a button instead of swipe functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Event onSwiped() will be triggered when the item will be completely swiped out. Since you're holding the item view, this never happen

[Here](https://codeburst.io/android-swipe-menu-with-recyclerview-8f28a235ff28) you can find an amazing tutorial where you can achieve this.